# How to stop then restart actions on a node in cocos2D

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm creating a rune casting application for iOS and I'm trying to get the actions for the current cast position to switch from the first to the second position in the rune spread.

After the first rune is placed, the current position basically moves off screen and doesn't do the action's I'm trying to get it to.

The code I have for the symbol I'm trying to work with:

```
    #import "CastingLayer.h"
    #import "RuneScene.h"


    @implementation CastingLayer

    @synthesize rotateSymbol;

-(id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

        castingLayerPosition = self.position;

        //CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];


        //______________________________________
        //RotateSymbol code for when it's needed
        //--------------------------------------

        CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

        rotateSymbol = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"rotatedSymbol.png"];
        [self addChild:rotateSymbol z:0 tag:1];
        first = CGPointMake(screenSize.width * (5.0f/12.0f), screenSize.height * 0.5f);
        second = CGPointMake(screenSize.width * 0.5f, screenSize.height * 0.5f);
        third = CGPointMake(screenSize.width * 0.20f, screenSize.height * 0.20f);
        fourth = CGPointMake(screenSize.width * 0.20f, screenSize.height * 0.10f);
        fifth = CGPointMake(screenSize.width * 0.20f, screenSize.height * 0.40f);
        sixth = CGPointMake(screenSize.width * 0.20f, screenSize.height * 0.60f);

        //rotateSymbol.position = CGPointMake(screenSize.width * (5.0f/12.0f), screenSize.height * 0.5f);


        [self symbolSpawnWithPosition:first];

        //runeArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:8];

       //rune test
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            //rune = [Runes runeWithParentNode:self andTexture:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"amathyst%i.png",i]];
            //[runeArray insertObject:rune atIndex:i];
        }
        rune0 = [Runes runeWithParentNode:self withTexture:@"amathyst0.png" withRuneNum:Rune0];
        rune1 = [Runes runeWithParentNode:self withTexture:@"amathyst1.png" withRuneNum:Rune1];
        rune2 = [Runes runeWithParentNode:self withTexture:@"amathyst2.png" withRuneNum:Rune2];
        rune3 = [Runes runeWithParentNode:self withTexture:@"amathyst3.png" withRuneNum:Rune3];
        rune4 = [Runes runeWithParentNode:self withTexture:@"amathyst4.png" withRuneNum:Rune4];
        rune5 = [Runes runeWithParentNode:self withTexture:@"amathyst5.png" withRuneNum:Rune5];
        rune6 = [Runes runeWithParentNode:self withTexture:@"amathyst6.png" withRuneNum:Rune6];
        rune7 = [Runes runeWithParentNode:self withTexture:@"amathyst7.png" withRuneNum:Rune7];
        [self symbolSpawnWithPosition:first];
        [self schedule:@selector(updateSymbol:) interval:0.1f];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) symbolSpawnWithPosition:(CGPoint)point{
    //CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    [rotateSymbol stopAllActions];
    rotateSymbol.position = point;


    CCRotateBy* rotate = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:2 angle:-360];
    CCFadeIn* fade = [CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:1];
    CCSpawn* spawn = [CCSpawn actionOne:fade two:rotate];
    CCRepeatForever* repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:rotate];

    [rotateSymbol runAction:spawn];
    [rotateSymbol runAction:repeat];
}
-(void) updateSymbol:(ccTime)delta{
    //static int currentRune = 0;

    Runes* currentRune = (Runes*)[self getChildByTag:current];


    if ([currentRune runeIsPlaced]) {
        CCFadeOut* fadeOut = [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:1];
        [rotateSymbol runAction:fadeOut];
        [self symbolSpawnWithPosition:second];

        switch (current) {
            case Rune0:
                current = Rune1;
                break;
            case Rune1:
                current = Rune2;
                break;
            case Rune2:
                current = Rune3;
                break;
            case Rune3:
                current = Rune4;
                break;
            case Rune4:
                current = Rune5;
                break;
            case Rune5:
                current = Rune6;
                break;
            case Rune6:
                current = Rune7;
                break;
            case Rune7:
                current = none;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my first app I've tried to make on my own, so forgive if it's not the best code ever.

But what I've done so far is create the runes with a tag I enumed so I can get the object when needed. SInce I want to use the spawn actions over and over, I put them in their own method which is called right after the rotateSymbol is initialized.

It works on start up, all the actions working perfectly, but it's when I place the first rune and try to transition to the second location is when the symbol freaks out and doesn't do what I need it to.

Thanks for any help that you can give :)

Comment: What do you mean by "freaks out"?

Comment: Also, could you explain what exactly the rune placement should look like? I think you could probably simplify it quite a bit but I just don't understand quite what it should be doing.

Comment: By "freaks out", once the rune gets placed, the spawnWithPosition method gets sent and the symbol zooms off screen.

Comment: I don't think you want to use: [self schedule:@selector(updateSymbol:) interval:0.1f]; actions should probably work for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what you're trying to do but from the description it seems like you're misusing actions. The easiest way to use actions is just once—fire and forget—they're lightweight and can be easily used and discarded. Rather that re-using them just recreate them.

Also look at using CCSequence it'll let you queue up several actions to take place one after another.

Comment: Well, I want the symbol to fade out and fade back into the new position once a rune is placed. But once I place it, the spawnWithPosition doesn't work again. and it freaks out like I mentioned above.

Comment: Yeah you really gotta go back to the start for me. I've got no idea what a rune caster should do. You place one image on the screen in a given point then place another until you get all 8 down? Is it like rolling 8 dice? Or is it like pulling runes out of a bag and placing them in a position?